# How to repeat ajax request depending return

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, jquery-countdown

I have this code :

```
.on('finish.countdown', function() {
                    var onEndAuction = function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "{{path('app_auction_end')}}",
                            data: {auctionId:{{ aReturn.oAuction.getId()}}},
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                if (data == 0) {
                                    setTimeout(onEndAuction, i_timer);
                                } else {
                                    document.location.reload(true);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    };
                });
```

I want if data == 0 need to make another call on `app_auction_end` after 10 sec. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Your nearly there, just call onEndAuction, doing `varEndAuction =` does nothing..  so there at the end after your function do ->  `};  onEndAuction(); `

Comment: @Keith sorry I don't undertstand the idea :(

Comment: Ok, I'll do as an answer..

Answer (score 1):

Give the operation a named function:

```
var someFunction = function () {
    $.ajax({
        //...
    });
};
```

Which you would then use for your `.on()` call:

```
.on('finish.countdown', someFunction)
```

And in the `success` handler, set a timeout for that function:

```
if (data == 0) {
    setTimeout(someFunction, i_timer);
}
```

Comment: @HareaCosticla: Since you defined the function in the scope of another function, you're not actually *calling* the function in the first place.  Either define it in window scope and use it as the callback to `.on()` as suggested in this answer, or invoke the `onEndAuction` function when you define it.  (The former seems a bit easier to understand in the long run.)

Answer (score 0):

```
.on('finish.countdown', function() {
  var onEndAuction = function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{{path('app_auction_end')}}",
      data: {auctionId:{{ aReturn.oAuction.getId()}}},
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data == 0) {
          setTimeout(onEndAuction, i_timer);
        } else {
          document.location.reload(true);
        }
      }
    });
  };
  //do our initial call otherwise it will never get called.
  onEndAuction();
});
```